# IntelliJ IDEA export settings from the cloud

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I have two `IntelliJ` accounts and I want to export settings from one account to another. On my main account all settings are synced in the cloud and when settings are synced option `File -> Export Settings` disappears. When I disable the sync all settings revert to default settings instead of persisting options from the cloud.

Is it possible to export IDE settings from `IntelliJ` cloud or between two accounts?

Comment: Settings from the cloud are stored under "config\jba_config" (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519). You could manually copy them.